# How can I display an image in a JS array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every method I try, I receive either underfined, or the description of the item, not the picture itself. Here's my code (with the different methods I've tried):

Add
show all

```
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input id="Name" /><br />
  <button onclick="searchByName()" class="btn btn-info">
    Search by Name
  </button>
  <input id="Search" />
  <label for="Search">Search</label>
  <br />
  <div class="alert alert-primary" id="display"><h1>My Contacts</h1></div>
</div>
<!-- <img id="imgFemale" src="images/female-icon-7897.png">
<img id="imgMale" src="images/person-icon-1687.png"> -->
<script>
  const imgFemale ="images/female-icon-7897.png"
  const imgMale = "images/person-icon-1687.png"
 
  let myContacts = [
    { Name: "Hubby ", gender: "male", Image: imgFemale.src="images/person-icon-1687.png"},
    { Name: "Mom", gender: "female", img: imgFemale.value },
    { Name: "Shannon", gender: "female", img: [imgFemale].innerHTML },
    { Name: "Dad", gender: "male", img: imgMale },
  ];
  function add() {
    console.log("add pressed");
    myContacts.push({
      id: myContacts.length + 1,
      Name: Name.value,
    });
  }

  function showAll() {
    console.log("showAll pressed");
    display.innerHTML = "<h1>My Contacts</h1>";
    for (let index = 0; index < myContacts.length; index++) {
      display.innerHTML += `<div class='alert alert-${myContacts[index]}'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick='remove(${index})'> Delete </button> 
        ${myContacts[index].Name} , ${myContacts[index].gender} , ${myContacts[index].img}</div>`;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you also share us the Error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it with `img` element like this: `<img src=${myContacts[index].img}/>`

```js
function showAll() {
    console.log("showAll pressed");
    display.innerHTML = "<h1>My Contacts</h1>";
    for (let index = 0; index < myContacts.length; index++) {
      display.innerHTML += `<div class='alert alert-${myContacts[index]}'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick='remove(${index})'> Delete </button> 
        ${myContacts[index].Name} , ${myContacts[index].gender} ,
        <img src=${myContacts[index].img}/> </div>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah except `.img` is still undefined because the different attempts (like `img: imgFemale.value` on a string) make no sense

Comment: the last object in the array have `img: imgMale` and `const imgMale = "images/person-icon-1687.png"` so the `src="images/person-icon-1687.png"`

Answer (score 0):

`{ Image: imgFemale.src="images/person-icon-1687.png"}`

This line doesn't make much sense. `Image:` expects a value (like `Image:"images/person-icon-1687.png"`), but instead, you're writing an assignment with a `=` sign (?)

Besides, `imgFemale` is a string, but you're doing `imgFemale.src="...png"`. A string has no `.src`. Same thing for `.value`.

`[imgFemale].innerHTML` just places the string `"images/person-icon-1687.png"` inside an array `["images/person-icon-1687.png"]`, and then, from this array, you are reading its `.innerHTML` property, which of course doesn't exist.

Finally, since your contacts already have a male/female gender, you don't need to repeat the image URL for male and female inside your object, you can just use the gender :

```
const images = {
    male : "images/person-icon-1687.png",
    female : "images/female-icon-7897.png"
}

let myContacts = [
    { Name: "Hubby ", gender: "male" },
    { Name: "Mom", gender: "female" },
    { Name: "Shannon", gender: "female" },
    { Name: "Dad", gender: "male" },
];
```

And then you just create images this way :

```
for (let contact of myContacts) {
    display.innerHTML += `<img src="${images[contact.gender]}"/>`
}
```

Also, not sure what you're trying to do with `alert-${myContacts[index]}` inside an HTML attribute, because `myContacts[index]` is an object?

Comment: I either get only the image, or the name, the gender, and then underfined. regarding that line- it was unnecessary, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `img: imgMale` and `myContacts[index].img`

```js
 const imgFemale ="images/female-icon-7897.png"
  const imgMale = "images/person-icon-1687.png"
 
  let myContacts = [
    { Name: "Hubby ", gender: "male", img: "images/person-icon-1687.png"},
    { Name: "Mom", gender: "female", img: imgFemale },
    { Name: "Shannon", gender: "female", img: imgFemale },
    { Name: "Dad", gender: "male", img: imgMale },
  ];
  function add() {
    console.log("add pressed");
    myContacts.push({
      id: myContacts.length + 1,
      Name: Name.value,
    });
  }

  function showAll() {
    console.log("showAll pressed");
    display.innerHTML = "<h1>My Contacts</h1>";
    for (let index = 0; index < myContacts.length; index++) {
      display.innerHTML += `<div class='alert alert-${myContacts[index]}'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick='remove(${index})'> Delete </button> 
        ${myContacts[index].Name} , ${myContacts[index].gender} , ${myContacts[index].img}</div>
        <img src=${myContacts[index].img}/> </div>`;
    }
  }
  

    showAll()
```

```html
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input id="Name" /><br />
  <button onclick="searchByName()" class="btn btn-info">
    Search by Name
  </button>
  <input id="Search" />
  <label for="Search">Search</label>
  <br />
  <div class="alert alert-primary" id="display"><h1>My Contacts</h1></div>
```